# How to prevent cooked noodles & dumplings from getting soggy

Tags: boiling, dumplings

I enjoy making spaetzel and gnocchi and have become quite good at it, but I always run into the same problem.

After boiling the dumplings, I put the cooked dumplings into a bowl, where water tends to collect and the dumplings at the bottom of the boil become soggy.

My temporary fix has been to mix the bowl every couple of minutes to ensure I don't end up with half soggy and half normal dumplings.

How can I prevent water from accumulating in a bowl and my dumplings from getting soggy?

Ideally, I would prefer top use typical kitchen tools and not have to buy a special tool to accomplish this.

Comment: Have you tried a colander, rather than a bowl?

Comment: @moscafj that would definitely work for smaller batches, but I tend to make them in large batches, they won't all fit in the colander

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest removing from boiling water and draining in a colander.  Then, removing to a cookie sheet so that the dumplings are in one layer, and more moisture can flash off.  If you are making large batches, I assume you are adding a further cook or re-heat step to finish.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a shot the next time I make gnocchi. I think it's exactly what I need

Comment: Broiler pan might work well too because the slots will let dumplings drain, and pan below will collect water.